# making bootstrap 4 cell behave as a bar graph

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a bootstrap 4 table. I want one of the columns to behave as a bar in a bar chart (see image attached). I have the conditional width part working but the "bar" won't fill the *height* of the table cell. Anyone know how to make it fill 90% of the height of the cell? Note, the text needs to be vertically centered in the "bar"

[image]

code used to get the bar so far is as follows (omitting irrelevant bits)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <table class="table table-borderless">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- <th scope="col">Rank</th> -->
                        <th scope="col">Items</th>
                        <th scope="col">Number</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div style="width: 75%; 
                                  background: rgb(128, 177, 133); 
                                  overflow:visible;">
                                Item 1
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            7
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `height` for the `<td>` and remove its padding. Try the code below.

```css
.bar-container {
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.bar {
  width: 10%;
  background: rgb(128, 177, 133);
  overflow: visible;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <table class="table table-borderless">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <!-- <th scope="col">Rank</th> -->
            <th scope="col">Items</th>
            <th scope="col">Number</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="bar-container">
              <div class="bar">
                Item 1
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              7
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="bar-container">
              <div class="bar" style="width:50%;">
                Item 1
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              7
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this almost works. the problem is that when the bar width is something low like 10%, the text "Item 1" starts to wrap inside that bar div. I tried putting the content outside the div but then it renders outside the bar. any fix for this issue?

Comment: @coffeeeee you can use `white-space: nowrap;` for that, have edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

Remove TD padding & add

```
<td style="padding: 0;">
    <div style="width: 75%; background: rgb(128, 177, 133); 
         overflow:visible;  padding:0.75rem;">
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <table class="table table-borderless">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- <th scope="col">Rank</th> -->
                        <th scope="col">Items</th>
                        <th scope="col">Number</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0;">
                            <div style="width: 75%; 
                                  background: rgb(128, 177, 133); 
                                  overflow:visible;  padding:0.75rem;">
                                Item 1
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            7
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this almost works. the problem is that when the bar width is something low like 10%, the text "Item 1" starts to wrap inside that bar div. I tried putting the content outside the div but then it renders outside the bar. any fix for this issue?

Comment: add this css `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

Td has a padding value from top and bottom. You need to decrease that value as::

```
tr td {
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```